# Nginx proxy_pass returns [No Host] while reverse proxying

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to reverse proxy an api with Nginx. I have the following configuration:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    upstream some_upstream {
            server  1.something.com;
            server  2.something.com;
    }

    server {

            listen 80;


            location ~/proxyNow/(?<zvar>(\w+))/(?<xvar>(\w+))/(?<yvar>(\w+))/ {
                    proxy_pass http://some_upstream/hello/something/$zvar/$xvar/$yvar/somethingelese;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                    proxy_cache maps_cache;
                    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  365d;
                    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
                    proxy_redirect off;

            }

    }


}
```

When I try to call the following url `http://localhost:82/proxyNow/1/2/3/?app_id=someAppId&app_code=someCode`

I get the following error message:

> Invalid URL
>
> The requested URL
>   "http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/hello/something/1/2/3/somethingelese", is
>   invalid. Reference #9.be35dd58.1489086561.5c9bd3c

It seems that the host cannot be retrieved by nginx. But if I execute the call directly:

`http://1.something.com/hello/something/$zvar/$xvar/$yvar/somethingelese?app_id=someAppId&app_code=someCode`

`http://2.something.com/hello/something/$zvar/$xvar/$yvar/somethingelese?app_id=someAppId&app_code=someCode`

It seems that Nginx for some reason is not able to resolve the host

Comment: You have duplicate entries for `proxy_set_header Host` and `proxy_cache_valid`. You should try correcting that first.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the doc.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> When location is specified using a regular expression.
>
> > In this case, the directive should be specified without a URI.

I suggest the following solution without expensive regex location.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

```
location /proxyNow/ {
  rewrite    /proxyNow/(?<zvar>(\w+))/(?<xvar>(\w+))/(?<yvar>(\w+))/.* /hello/something/$zvar/$xvar/$yvar/somethingelese$is_args?$args break;
  proxy_pass http://some_upstream;
... other nginx diretives;
}
```